# How do I fix an xstring exception with tmxparser? SFML/C++

Tags: c++, parsing, sfml, tmx

I currently I have a problem that when I run my code, it stops at an exception at line 3467 in the xstring system file. Here is a few screenshots of it:

[image: Exception Popup]

[image: Current code that it ends at]

[image: Output].

I figured it had to do something to do with loading the file or the file is corrupted. Something is wrong with how it parses. Here is the link to my [Github page](https://github.com/JonahHenriksson/GameCompetition). I used the tmxlite parser to load the file, here is also a link to the [tmxlite Github page](https://github.com/fallahn/tmxlite). Thanks so much! Sorry if this is a dumb question. I really have not programmed C++ for long, and done it without proper training. This is the [tmx file link](https://github.com/JonahHenriksson/GameCompetition/blob/master/Game/Game/map1.tmx)

Comment: Please always post code as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: Without the actual tmx file in question, it will be hard to help. If the parser complains, my guess is that the parser is correct and the file is "wrong" or is using a feature that the SFML map cannot understand.

Comment: Sorry, the .tmx file is on the github. Here is the [link](https://github.com/JonahHenriksson/GameCompetition/blob/master/Game/Game/map1.tmx).

Comment: Questions should not depend on external resources. Please try to create a self-contained question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I will now try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am so sorry for those who looked at this. It turns out I needed to edit my tmx files to include the tsx files and add the tsx files to the project. I am so sorry if I made anyone look for the answer when all I had to do was just use the resources in front of me. Thanks to underscore_d for telling me make it into a MCVE, leading me to find the answer. All this time... Sorry anyone whose time I wasted.

Comment: I can't do it till tomorrow.

Comment: Heh, is that a Stackoverflow restriction? :-S